# A question about estimates for nonlinear structure of linear elliptic operator

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

I am reading *Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second order* written by David Gilbarg and Neil S. Trudinger. In section 8.5. global boundedness of weak solutions, I meet some problems.

> Define \begin{align*}
>     A^i(x,z,p)=a^{ij}p_j+b^i(x)z-f^i(x),\\
>     B(x,z,p)=c^i(x)p_i+d(x)z-g(x)
> \end{align*} by using Schwarz inequality, we have the estimates,
> \begin{align*}
>     &p_iA^i(x,z,p)\geq \frac{\lambda}{2}|p|^2-\frac{1}{\lambda}(|bz|^2+|f|^2),\\
>     &B(x,z,p)\leq |c||p| +|dz|+|g|.
> \end{align*} If let $\bar{z}=|z|+k$ and $\bar{k}=\lambda^{-2}(|b|^2+|c|^2+k^{-2}|f|^2)+\lambda^{-1}(|d|+k^{-1}|g|$ for some $k>0$. We obtain then, for any $0<\epsilon<1$,
> \begin{align*}
>     p_iA^i(x,z,p)\geq \frac{\lambda}{2}(|p|^2-2\bar{b}\bar{z}^2), \\ 
>     |\bar{z}B(x,z,p)|\leq \frac{\lambda}{2}(\epsilon|p|^2+\frac{\bar{b}}{\epsilon}\bar{z}^2).
> \end{align*}

My question is, how can we get the inequality$B(x,z,p)\leq |c||p| +|dz|+|g|.$ Here is my attemption:

By $B(x,z,p)\leq |c||p| +|dz|+|g|$, we get $$\bar{z}B(x,z,p)\leq \bar{z}|c||p| +\bar{z}|dz|+\bar{z}|g|.$$
For the first part, we have $$\bar{z}|c||p|\leq \frac{1}{2}(\lambda\epsilon|p|^2+\frac{|c|^2}{\epsilon\lambda}\bar{z}^2),$$ which seems closely related to the inequality I want to prove. But for $\bar{z}|d\cdot z|$ and $\bar{z}|g|$, I have no idea how to deal with it.